# Как подключить FancyBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: изображение]

Как подключить скрипт [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) к странице товара, чтобы открывалось полно-размерное фото и можно было листать галерею? Сложность в том, что методы описанные в документации не срабатывают. К примеру скрипт зума `elevatezoom.js`, который уже присутствует запускается через обработчик `app.js`. Поведение видно на [сайте](http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/men/shirts/slim-fit-dobby-oxford-shirt-475.html)
Буду признателен любым подсказкам. Возможно подключение должно происходить не в `media.phtml`(создающий разметку), а в обработчике `app.js` так как там прописан сценарий для зума и галереи с изменением классов. По логике и новый скрипт нужно прописывать там же для корректной работы.

```js
// PDP - image zoom - needs to be available outside document.ready scope
// ==============================================

var ProductMediaManager = {
    IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD: 20,
    imageWrapper: null,

    destroyZoom: function() {
        $j('.zoomContainer').remove();
        $j('.product-image-gallery .gallery-image').removeData('elevateZoom');
    },

    createZoom: function(image) {
        // Destroy since zoom shouldn't be enabled under certain conditions
        ProductMediaManager.destroyZoom();

        if(
            // Don't use zoom on devices where touch has been used
            PointerManager.getPointer() == PointerManager.TOUCH_POINTER_TYPE
            // Don't use zoom when screen is small, or else zoom window shows outside body
            || Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:" + bp.medium + "px)")
        ) {
            return; // zoom not enabled
        }

        if(image.length <= 0) { //no image found
            return;
        }

        if(image[0].naturalWidth && image[0].naturalHeight) {
            var widthDiff = image[0].naturalWidth - image.width() - ProductMediaManager.IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD;
            var heightDiff = image[0].naturalHeight - image.height() - ProductMediaManager.IMAGE_ZOOM_THRESHOLD;

            if(widthDiff < 0 && heightDiff < 0) {
                //image not big enough

                image.parents('.product-image').removeClass('zoom-available');

                return;
            } else {
                image.parents('.product-image').addClass('zoom-available');
            }
        }

        image.elevateZoom({
      zoomType: "inner", 
   cursor: "crosshair" 
  });
    },

    swapImage: function(targetImage) {
        targetImage = $j(targetImage);
        targetImage.addClass('gallery-image');

        ProductMediaManager.destroyZoom();

        var imageGallery = $j('.product-image-gallery');

        if(targetImage[0].complete) { //image already loaded -- swap immediately

            imageGallery.find('.gallery-image').removeClass('visible');

            //move target image to correct place, in case it's necessary
            imageGallery.append(targetImage);

            //reveal new image
            targetImage.addClass('visible');

            //wire zoom on new image
            ProductMediaManager.createZoom(targetImage);

        } else { //need to wait for image to load

            //add spinner
            imageGallery.addClass('loading');

            //move target image to correct place, in case it's necessary
            imageGallery.append(targetImage);

            //wait until image is loaded
            imagesLoaded(targetImage, function() {
                //remove spinner
                imageGallery.removeClass('loading');

                //hide old image
                imageGallery.find('.gallery-image').removeClass('visible');

                //reveal new image
                targetImage.addClass('visible');

                //wire zoom on new image
                ProductMediaManager.createZoom(targetImage);
            });

        }
    },

    wireThumbnails: function() {
        //trigger image change event on thumbnail click
        $j('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var jlink = $j(this);
            var target = $j('#image-' + jlink.data('image-index'));

            ProductMediaManager.swapImage(target);
        });
    },

    initZoom: function() {
        ProductMediaManager.createZoom($j(".gallery-image.visible")); //set zoom on first image
    },

    init: function() {
        ProductMediaManager.imageWrapper = $j('.product-img-box');

        // Re-initialize zoom on viewport size change since resizing causes problems with zoom and since smaller
        // viewport sizes shouldn't have zoom
        $j(window).on('delayed-resize', function(e, resizeEvent) {
            ProductMediaManager.initZoom();
        });

        ProductMediaManager.initZoom();

        ProductMediaManager.wireThumbnails();

        $j(document).trigger('product-media-loaded', ProductMediaManager);
    }
};

$j(document).ready(function() {
    ProductMediaManager.init();
});
```

```html
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<div class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <div class="product-image-gallery">
        <img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />

        <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
            <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
                 class="gallery-image"
                 src="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>"
                 data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 <script>
     jQuery(function($){
   $(".gallery-image").fancybox();
  });
 </script>
</div>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
    <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
                     width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after'); ?>
```

Comment: установите модуль https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jquery-lightboxes-fancybox-pirobox-etc.html он бесплатный зачем мучиться.

Comment: Да лучший вариант замутить свой велосипед )) который будет с багами и поверьте результат будет хуже, чем расширение которое уже не первый год поддерживаеться и в котором правяться баги. Да и одним селектом вы не замедлите работу сайта, вы быстрее её замедлите не правильным подключением js, и кучей ненужного кода.

Comment: Я не флужу но я уверен что вы не правильно просто настроили плагин, 2-й шаг делали

Comment: jQuery вообще нет в magento там только prototype...

Comment: Вопрос актуален, прошу помочь с подключением функции лайтбокса.

Comment: Поведение видно на сайте, что получилось, ссылка в описании. Подключение стандартное, что описано в принципе в трёх ответах, но к сожалению оно не работает. Подозреваю, что нужно связать Фансибокс с обработчиком, чтобы небыло конфликта.

Answer (score 2):

### Пример галереи

Взято [отсюда](http://fancybox.net/#manual2), в самом низу пункт "Image gallery".

Браузерные инструменты разработчика подсказывают, что на

```
<a id="manual2" href="javascript:;" title="">Image gallery</a>
```

висит обработчик события `click`.

Код обработчика:

```
function() {
  $.fancybox([
    'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7308/15783866983_27160395b9_b.jpg',
    'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2880/10346743894_0cfda8ff7a_b.jpg',
    {
      'href': 'http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_b.jpg',
      'title': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
    }
  ], {
    'padding': 0,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'image',
    'changeFade': 0
  });
}
```

Получается, что первый аргумент - список ресурсов для пролистывания, второй - настройки всплывающего окна.

### Решение конкретно для вас

Скопируйте и выполните на вашем сайте следующий код:

```
jQuery.fancybox([
  'http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/m/s/msj003t_2.jpg',
  'http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/m/s/msj003a_2.jpg',
  'http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/m/s/msj003b_2.jpg'
], {
  'padding': 0,
  'transitionIn': 'none',
  'transitionOut': 'none',
  'type': 'image',
  'changeFade': 0
});
```

Запуск этого кода прицепите к нужному html-элементу по полной аналогии с примером. Успехов)

#### UPD - детальная инструкция по встраиванию в ваш сайт:

1) Как обнаружил в вашем коде, в элементах .gallery-image[data-zoom-image] хранятся адреса картинок, и вдобавок вы эти элементы сортируете, в зависимости от текущей картинки.

2) Показ всплывающего окна с галереей повесим например на `div.zoomContainer` при клике.

3) У нас есть данные, которые показывать, у нас есть событие, по которому это нужно делать. Осталось убрать все старые вызовы fancybox и заменить на следующее:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".zoomContainer").click(function(){
        $.fancybox(
            $.map($(".gallery-image[data-zoom-image]"),function(e){return e.src;}).reverse(),
            {'padding': 0,'transitionIn': 'none','transitionOut': 'none','type': 'image','changeFade': 0}
        );
    });
});
```

**Личное мнение:** У вашего сайта странная особенность - на некоторых элементах висит по 20-30+ обработчиков. Вероятно их изобилие и безликость и вызывают т.н. "конфликты обработчиков". Не усложняйте себе задачу, старайтесь такого избегать, например, объединяя сотни вызываемых функций в один обработчик вместо ста обработчиков по одной функции в каждом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Суть в том, что это прямой вызов и он изначально конфликтует с обработчиком (первая часть кода). Действие же должно происходить по классам (пример подключения во второй части кода). В первой части кода видно, что прописано для галереи и зума, тут обычный способ подключения к сожалению не срабатывает.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, поясните, в чем заключается конфликт? Для классов - выберите элементы по классам и повесьте на него обработчик `.addEventListener(функция показа всплывашки)` или `.click(...)` в случае jQuery

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, ссылку на мой [тестовый сайт](http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/men/shirts/slim-fit-dobby-oxford-shirt-475.html) и там видно как ведёт себя Фансибокс после нажатия и закрытия и то, что в нём не работает галерея. И два кода, первый это обработчик и второй генерирует разметку, там и подключил фансибокс. К сожалению у меня не хватает знаний, чтобы его вставить как полагается в коды выше.

Comment: @SergeyEremin дополнил ответ детальной инструкцией для вашего сайта

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что ваш код нужно вписать где у меня строчка `jQuery(function($){`? Это я сам там вставил подключение, возможно оно должно быть в обработчике.

Comment: Добавил ваш код, к сожалению не работает. В целом я прочитал куски кода, что здесь выложил, в обработчике как раз таки прописано для зума и галереи, по логике думается, что подключение и фансибокса там же должно быть. Насчет большинства обработчиков, вы имеете ввиду, что разные скрипты не соединены в один?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на лицензию fancybox (насколько я помню, для проектов типа интернет магазина - она платная), если вы ее не приобрели - приобретите, если нет желания приобретать можете попробовать использовать jQuery Colorbox или что-либо другое (colorbox точно с MIT лицензией). В вашем объекте `ProductMediaManager` есть метод `init`, попробуйте в нем проинициализировать вашу галерею `".gallery-image"`. Именно этот метод срабатывает на domready:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    ProductMediaManager.init();
});
```

И если есть возможность - выложите ваш код (сгенеренную страничку) на плункер или фидл, гам проще будет разобраться. Например не ясно когда сработает этот код (т.к. нет цельной страницы):

```
<script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(".gallery-image").fancybox();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! К сожалению если выложу всё это на плункер или фидл, оно не будет работать в любом случае. Вверху выложены два кода: второй php генерирует html-разметку, первый кусок - это скрипт обработчик, в котором написан сценарий для скрипта зума и поведения галереи. Вот тут и задача подключить Фансибокс либо в обработчике, либо к html-разметке. Ну а Фансибокс бесплатный.

Comment: Если используете в коммерческих целях имейте ввиду: http://sites.fastspring.com/fancyapps/product/store

Answer (score -1):

Из моего личного проекта:
Для картинок которые вы хотите сделать как галерея нужно следующее:

1. Обернуть все картинки в тег `<a>` и дать тегу `class='fancybox'` (например).
2. Добавить `data-fancybox-group` для тега `<a>` для группирования их в "галереи"
3. Атрибутом `href` для тегов `<a>` сделать ссылку на данную фотографию. (контентом данного тега будет тег `<img>` с `src` на эту же картинку)
4. И в конечном итоге, после прогрузки DOOM (или ивента onLoad|onReady) запустить

   `$("a.fancybox").fancybox();`
   (при условии что у вас установлен **jquery** а так же и сам **fancybox**.

Функция `fancybox();` которую мы применяем ко всем нашим тегам `<a>` принимает объект настроек первым параметром. Пример:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'type': 'image',
    'changeFade': 0
  });
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Данный вариант проверил изначально, к сожалению он не работает, конфликт с обработчиком.